# Making a TypeFace Helper Class

Tags: android, class, typeface

I have about 10-15 `Activity`'s or `Fragment`'s in my app.  I have about 5 different TypeFaces I am using (mostly `Roboto` variants).

In almost every Class I have to do this:

```
roboto_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
        "fonts/roboto_light.ttf");
roboto_thin = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
        "fonts/roboto_thin.ttf");
roboto_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
        "fonts/roboto_regular.ttf");
```

Not all classes use all five.  Some use 1, some use 4, some use 3, while others may use a *different* combo of 3.

Declaring this code in every class seems redundant.  Can the 5 fonts all be declared once, maybe when app starts and then I use a Helper Class to statically use them?

I am not sure if I have to do this -- if possible at all -- in a class that extends Application, or just a regular Class that I can statically call?  And where would this be initialized?

Comment: regular class.  just expose a static getter for each one or a single static getter and a public static constant for each typeface so you can say TypefaceHelper.getTypeface(TypefaceHelper.ROBOTO_THIN)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am not sure if I have to do this -- if possible at all -- in a class
>   that extends Application, or just a regular Class that I can
>   statically call?

Either way will do. There are a couple of sample implementations out there, which all 'cache' the last few type faces created. If I recall correctly, in more recent Android platforms caching also happens under the hood. Anyways, a basic implementation would look like this:

```
public class Typefaces{

    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String name){
        synchronized(cache){
            if(!cache.containsKey(name)){
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s.ttf", name));
                cache.put(name, t);
            }
            return cache.get(name);
        }
    }    
}
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904#c3

This is using a helper class, but you could also make it part your own `Application` extension. It creates type faces lazily: it attempts to retrieve the type face from the local cache first, and only instantiates a new one if not available from cache. Simply supply a `Context` and the name of the type face to load.

Comment: Quick question, when checking for assets in each context, the app has to recreate a typeface when delivering an other context (activity). Isn't it better to access the ApplicationContext so you share all the typefaces across your application?

Comment: @Chris: what makes you say that typefaces have to be recreated across different contexts? Personally, I've always used the `Application` (context) approach, but as far as I know, assets don't differ per context. That is, the same `AssetManager` is returned for each context instance.

Comment: @MH. do you know since when Android does cache itself typefaces? I remember seeing this in sources but can’t remember where.

Comment: @mvai: [This commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/46926698996d3857a650ed535024a88dbeaff1e1) to the `Typeface` class introduced a basic caching mechanism and was released in Android 4.1.1, although it only appears to be used for the `create(...)` methods, and not i.e. `createFromAsset(...)` or `createFromFile(...)` (although I may be overlooking it).

Answer (score 0):

If you are one of the few lucky ones using minApi 24 you don't have to do anything at all as `createFromAsset()` has a `Typeface` cache implemented starting API 24. If not, refer to @MH.'s answer.