# Android : Proper way to use custom typeface in

Tags: android, fonts, android-typeface

What is the right way to use typeface in Android? I see many examples using custom XML tag for text view. I tried to to set in Java to normal text view and it works fine, so what is the reason to use custom fields?

Answer (score 1):

When using a custom Typeface its best to add the Typeface to your /assets directory in your project. It is fairly lightweight to do the following:

```
TextView customTypefaceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTypefaceTextView);
Typeface customTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Custom_Typeface.ttf");
customTypefaceTextView.setTypeface(customTypeface);
```

Just remember that finding your assets will be related to the current `Context` so if your using custom fonts in a Fragment vs. Activity you will want to call `getActivity().getAssets()` instead of just `getAssets()`.

This is a reference to the quick tip from : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/customize-android-fonts--mobile-1601

Additionally it may be more practical to create a class that `extends TextView` to help you have a more practical implementation to a custom Font that can be used for the `TextView`s you want to add a custom font to like so:

```
public class CustomTitleTextView extends TextView {

private Context m_classContext          = null;
private Typeface m_customTypeFace       = null;

    // Default Constructor
public CustomTitleTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.m_classContext = context;
    createRobotoTitleTextView();
}

    // Default Constructor
public CustomTitleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.m_classContext = context;
    createRobotoTitleTextView();
}

    // Default Constructor
public CustomTitleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.m_classContext = context;
    createRobotoTitleTextView();
}

    // Adds the Typeface to the TextView
private void createRobotoTitleTextView()
{
    m_customTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(m_classContext.getAssets(), "Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(m_customTypeFace);

}


}
```

And then you can use this in XML in any layout

```
<packagename.CustomTitleTextView
  android:id="@+id/customTitleTextView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Update**

These are a few ways that I have had success implementing custom fonts. The sample showing how to add a custom `TextView` via `extends TextView` then adding it in XML is not necessary it just provides a skeleton of how to create your `TextView` as a re-useable object rather than doing it dynamically in your Activity or Fragment.

Good luck!

Comment: Note that on some android levels, typefaces created from Assets are not cached and reused properly.  If you re going to use the typeface in multiple areas you should include a caching mechanism to avoid memory leaks, such as the one posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17283657/3194316

Comment: well i am loading them exactly this way now but without the

`<packagename.CustomTitleTextView`
`  android:id="@+id/customTitleTextView"`
`  android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
`  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`


so why do i need those ?

i have normal textview such as


`
<TextView
  android:text="@string/play"
  android:textStyle="bold"        
  android:textColor="#fff"
  android:textSize="@dimen/font2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
`

Comment: This is just an alternative way to do it so your code is reusable. You could additionally create a helper method that takes in your textview as the parameter and call texview.setTypeface(customTypeFace); is your font not displaying? If so please add your code to the post so i can assist in helping solve that issue. I am showing you some common ways to use custom fonts.