# Best way to assign font typeface to textview

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, android-fonts, android-typeface

I wonder what would be **the best way** to assign a font typeface to a TextView view? Is it better to create a custom TextView class which extends TextView or use setTypeFace attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create folder assets(src/main/assets/ in AndroidStudio) and make a sub-folder fonts , copy your fonts in them

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
    "fonts/youi.ttf");
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_t);
 tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: I know this. Consider I have a ListView item xml file and there are TextViews inside. And I want to use custom fonts for each TextView, should I send typeface as an input to custom adapter class so then I can assign it by using the code you mentioned?

Comment: Yes , Assign fonts in getView() .

Comment: And if I have more than one font type, should I send a list of typefaces? Is it the best and easiest possible way?

Comment: Please be careful as there is a known problem with `createFromAsset`. Instead of maintaining its reference, it tries to recreate the typeface each time it's called. You should probably cache it if you plan to use it often.

Comment: See this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293437/custom-font-for-android-listview

Comment: @alex-kolpa What you mean exactly? Is it wrong to this in main activity and send fonts list to adapter?
  
fontList = new ArrayList<Typeface>();
  fontList.add(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/gautami.ttf"));
  fontList.add(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/clash.ttf"));
  fontList.add(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/tekton_pro.otf"));

Comment: No, that works fine in this case, since you're only creating each font once. But I have a few apps where I use custom fonts all over the place. For those cases I use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17283657/4258911)

Comment: I know. It's a good answer. But I'd like to hear more from different users. More opinions, better result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kotlin version for this

```
val openSansLight: Typeface by lazy { Typeface.createFromAsset(context, "font/os_light.ttf"); }
textView.typeface = openSansLight
```

Answer (score 0):

Font is now part of the app resource! You can now use the font family attribute to change the typeface in xml. Create font resource directory and you can put font files in there.

```
android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"
```

Using code

```
val typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.myfont)
textView.typeface = typeface
```

Refer the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#kotlin) for more